# Print Specific Cookie with Selenium Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to print a specific cookies value from a cookie list. I tried the following but no success:

```
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
for name in cookies_list:
    print name['cookiename']
```

What can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {} # create dictionary
for cookie in cookies_list:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value'] # populate it

print(cookies_dict)
```

Comment: This works. thanks, will accept answer when its time

Comment: Happy to hear it! What do you mean ` when its time`?

Comment: i meant it takes 10 mins until i can accept ur answer haha

Comment: Didn't hear about timings for marking answers. Ok ))